# Как убрать разницу в регистрах js

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Есть код для живого поиска по странице, но он сравнивает значения в 100% точности, то есть если ты пишешь в поиске слово в нижнем регистре, то это же слово в, но только в верхнем регистре ты не найдешь. Как сделать, что бы регистр не влиял на ввод в условии.

```js
document.querySelector('#elastic').oninput = function() {
  let val = this.value.trim();
  let elasticItem = document.querySelectorAll('.elastic div');

  if (val != '') {

    elasticItem.forEach(function(elem) {
      if (elem.innerText.search(val) == -1) {
        elem.classList.add('hide');
      } else {
        elem.classList.remove('hide');
      }
    });
  } else {
    elasticItem.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.remove('hide');
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search1">
  <input type="text" id="elastic" placeholder="Search FAQ">
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <p>ORDER</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elastic">
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>Can I return all or part of my order?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod

  </div>
</div>

<div class="elastic">
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>Is there a limit to how much I can order online? Why did I receive an order max error notification?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    To properly manage inventory for all online customers, an order quantity limit of 1/2 pallet per item, and re-order frequency of 15 days has been set for online orders. If customers are able to order items in full pallet quantities, please contact us
    regarding moving to direct service.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elastic">
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>Can I return all or part of my order?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('#elastic').oninput = function() {
  let val = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  let elasticItem = document.querySelectorAll('.elastic div');

  if (val != '') {

    elasticItem.forEach(function(elem) {
      if (elem.innerText.toLowerCase().search(val) == -1) {
        elem.classList.add('hide');
      } else {
        elem.classList.remove('hide');
      }
    });
  } else {
    elasticItem.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.remove('hide');
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search1">
  <input type="text" id="elastic" placeholder="Search FAQ">
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <p>ORDER</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elastic">
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>Can I return all or part of my order?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod

  </div>
</div>

<div class="elastic">
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>Is there a limit to how much I can order online? Why did I receive an order max error notification?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    To properly manage inventory for all online customers, an order quantity limit of 1/2 pallet per item, and re-order frequency of 15 days has been set for online orders. If customers are able to order items in full pallet quantities, please contact us
    regarding moving to direct service.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elastic">
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>Can I return all or part of my order?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы уже сами и ответили на свой вопрос: просто приводите текст **и** искомое значение к одному регистру: `toUpperCase` или `toLowerCase`

Comment: я пробовал к elasticItem добавить toLowerCase, но не получалось, появлялась ошибка с TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).toLowerCase is not a function at

Comment: @user480491 а зачем к item если у вас сравнивается innerText? вот к нему (к тексту) и добавляйте. А elasticItem  - это коллекция элементов, логично что там ничего с не сработает

Comment: @user480491 Алексей вам хороший вариант посоветовал, я его вам в ответе как раз реализовал.